# use variable image in setbeamertheme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am defining this `beamer style` file, and using it in my beamer tex.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mat theme}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.04\paperheight,dp=2.25ex]{title in head/foot}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\paperwidth}%
            \hskip10pt\insertshortauthor%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\paperwidth}%
            \centering
            \inserttitle\vfill%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.10\paperwidth}%
            \begin{flushright}
                \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
                    \includegraphics[width=.1\pagewidth]{/tmp/g1915.png} %PATH HARDCODED
                \else
                    \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill%
                \fi
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill%
}
```

The only problem is the for the logo here, i.e.

```
\includegraphics[width=.1\pagewidth]{/tmp/g1915.png}
```

as you can see, the path is hard coded. I am looking for some variable here, so that, in my main tex file, I may have

```
\setlogo{/tmp/g1915.png}
```

to get the same effect.

How I can do that?

**UPDATE** I have tried egreg's reply and not working (Sorry, I changed again, so I dont have the exact error), but here is the `mwe`:

**mwe.sty**

```
%mwe
%
%

\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HOW TO DEFINE ITEMS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\insertframetitle{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}{\begingroup\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\textbullet\endgroup}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\begingroup\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\textbullet\endgroup}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mat theme}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.04\paperheight,dp=2.25ex]{title in head/foot}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\paperwidth}%
            \hskip10pt\insertshortauthor%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\paperwidth}%
            \centering
            \inserttitle\vfill%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.10\paperwidth}%
            \begin{flushright}
                \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
                    \includegraphics[width=.06\pagewidth]{/tmp/logo.png}%\hskip20pt
                \else
                    \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill%
                \fi
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill%
}
```

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{mwe}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**logo.png**
[image]

Comment: Please, add a full (minimal) example so the proposed solution can be tested.

Answer (score 3):

The usual procedure would be

```
\newcommand{\matthemelogo}{example-image}% initialize to something
\newcommand{\setmatthemelogo}[1]{%
  \gdef\matthemelogo{#1}%
}
```

and in the code for the template use `\matthemelogo` instead of the hardwired text.

In your document you can say

```
\setmatthemelogo{/tmp/g1915.png}
```

(Untested because of lack of a MWE)

Comment: mwe is provided. Kindly have a look.