# theme with variable image

Tags: styles

Please check this **mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table,handout]{beamer}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{034da1}
\usetheme{Mwe}
\title{mwe}
\author{mwe}
\institute{mwe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello}
\begin{frame}{Hello Title}
    Hello text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding **beamerthemeMwe.sty**:

```
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=dcol}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=dcol,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=dcol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mat theme}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.04\paperheight,dp=2.25ex]{title in head/foot}%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\paperwidth}%
            \hskip10pt\insertshortauthor%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.60\paperwidth}%
            \centering
            \inserttitle%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.10\paperwidth}%
            \begin{flushright}
                \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
                    \includegraphics[width=.06\pagewidth]{example-image-a}%\hskip20pt
                \else
                    \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill%
                \fi
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{b@matshade}{\the\paperwidth}
    {rgb(0pt)=(1,1,1); rgb(3pt)=(0.8,0.8,0.8);rgb(5pt)=(0.75,0.75,0.75)}
}
```

The problem is, I would like insert the image from preamble. At present, the logo is hard coded, as `example-image-a`:

```
  \begin{flushright}
      \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
         \includegraphics[width=.06\pagewidth]{example-image-a}%\hskip20pt
       \else
         \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill%
      \fi
```

I am trying to change it, with some option, so that I can change the image in preamble as

```
\setlogo{example-image-b}
```

How I can do that?

I have asked this question before, in [use variable image in setbeamertheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573282/use-variable-image-in-setbeamertheme?noredirect=1#comment1444206_573282) but the answer is not working, and I had got error (the exact output is not with me right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your beamer style, define `\setlogo` as follows.

```
\newcommand\setlogo[1]{\def\@logo{#1}}
```

Moreover, change the part where you load the logo to the following code. If the logo hasn't been set, it will print the page number, otherwise the logo.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.10\paperwidth}%
    \begin{flushright}
        \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
            \ifcsname @logo\endcsname
                \includegraphics[width=.06\paperwidth]{\@logo}%
            \else
                \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill
            \fi
        \else
            \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill
        \fi
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
```

[image]

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table,handout]{beamer}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{034da1}
\usetheme{Mwe}
\setlogo{example-image-a}
\title{mwe}
\author{mwe}
\institute{mwe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello}
\begin{frame}{Hello Title}
    Hello text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
% beamerthemeMwe.sty
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=dcol}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=dcol,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=dcol}

\newcommand\setlogo[1]{\def\@logo{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mat theme}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.04\paperheight,dp=2.25ex]{title in head/foot}%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\paperwidth}%
            \hskip10pt\insertshortauthor%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.60\paperwidth}%
            \centering
            \inserttitle%
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.10\paperwidth}%
            \begin{flushright}
                \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
                  \ifcsname @logo\endcsname
                    \includegraphics[width=.06\paperwidth]{\@logo}%\hskip20pt
                  \else
                    \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill
                  \fi
                \else
                    \insertframenumber{}\hfill\vfill
                \fi
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{b@matshade}{\the\paperwidth}
    {rgb(0pt)=(1,1,1); rgb(3pt)=(0.8,0.8,0.8);rgb(5pt)=(0.75,0.75,0.75)}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. working perfectly.